# Updating Parents state from Child without triggering a rerender of Child in React

Tags: reactjs, rendering, single-page-application

So I'm trying to build a single page app in react.

**What I want:**
On the page you can visit different pages like normal. On one page (index) i want a button the user can click that expands another component into view with a form. This component or form should be visible on all pages once expanded.

**The Problem:**
The index page loads some data from an api, so when the index component gets mounted, an fetch call is made. But when the user clicks the "Expand form"-Button, the state of the Parent component gets updated as expected, but the children get rerendered which causes the index component to fetch data again, which is not what I want.

**What I tried**

```
// Parent Component
const App => props => {
    const [composer, setComposer] = useState({
        // ...
        expanded: false,
    });

    const expandComposer = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setComposer({
            ...composer,
            expanded: true
    });

    return(
        // ...
        <Switch>
            // ...
            <Route
                exact path={'/'}
                component={() => (<Index onButtonClick={expandComposer}/>)}
        // ....
        {composer.expanded && (
            <Composer/>
        )};
    );
};

// Index Component
const Index=> props => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        // load some data
    }, []);

    if(isLoading) {
        // show spinner
    } else {
        return (
            // ...
            <button onClick={props.onButtonClick}>Expand Composer</button>
            // ...
        );
    };
};
```

So with my approach, when the button is clicked, the Index component fetched the data again and the spinner is visible for a short time. But I dont want to remount Index, or at least reload the data if possible

Comment: Will be great if you make codesandbox...

Comment: Usually `Rect.memo` would solve your problem. But to be sure you need to share how you're passing `onButtonClick` to `Index`

Comment: @Dupocas i pass it via `component={() => (onButtonClick="expandComposer"/>)}` to Index. Oh and I tried React.memo but it behaves still the same

Comment: The anonymous function is a new object every render, which prevents memo from working. Either make it always pass the same instance, or add the second parameter to memo and ignore the prop.

Comment: @thathat I fixed the line of code in Parent, maybe it's a bit clearer now what I tried to do. How can I make sure the same instance gets passed every time? I tried Dupocas answer, but with the same result, probably due to this problem with the instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here. First, `React` will by default re render all child components when the parent gets updated. To avoid this behavior you should explicitly define when a component should update. In class based components `PureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate` are the way to go, and in functional components `React.memo` is the equivalent to `PureComponent`. A `PureComponent` will only update when one of it's `props` change. So you could implement it like this:

```
const Index = () =>{/**/}
export default React.memo(Index)
```

But this won't solve your problem because of the second issue. `PureComponent` and `React.memo` perform a `shallow comparison` in `props`, and you are passing an inline function as a `prop` which will return `false` in every `shallow comparison` cause a new instance of the function is created every render.

```
<Child onClick={() => this.onClick('some param')} />
```

This will actually create a new function every render, causing the comparison to always return `false`. A workaround this is to pass the parameters as a second `prop`, like this

```
<Child onClick={this.onClick} param='some param' />
```

And inside `Child`

```
<button onClick={() => props.onClick(props.param)} />
```

Now you're not creating any functions on render, just passing a reference of `this.onClick` to your child.

Comment: I just tested this solution and it works BUT only if I render the child component outside of <Switch></Switch>. Not exactly what I wanted, but closer to it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully familiar with your style of React, I do not use them special state functions.

Why not add a boolean in the parent state, called "fetched".

if (!fetched) fetch(params, ()=>setState({ fetched: true ));

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I used `component={() => ...}` instead of `render={() => ...}` when defining the route. As explained in [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component), using `component` always rerenders the component. Dupocas' answer now works perfectly :)